# Need to get facebook feed without user login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My company wants to post our company facebook newsfeed on our intranet; however, there are a few caveats. We block employee's from accessing facebook through their browsers making it impossible for them to log in and get a user access token.

*[edit: we do allow our web server through to facebook which is how I am talking to the graph API. I am using PHP (see code sample below)]*.

I need a way to get this to work or concrete evidence that it won't.

I can get the app token generated and the server has access to facebook. I've tried to extend the access token that I am generating in the explore but I get an error stating that the token does not belong to my app. Anyway, here is what I have done:

1. created app (worked)
2. using PHP i am able to generate the app token and get my basic data but not the feed

   `$authToken = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id={$app_id}&client_secret={$app_secret}");`

   `$data['feed_data'] = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/{$profile_id}?fields=id,name,feed&{$authToken}");`

Let me repeat, I just need the feed off of our facebook page to display on our site. Also, the like plugin won't work as it is blocked by the firewall.

Comment: You can not extend an app access token – that works only for short-lived user access tokens. You should get a page access token (using an extended user token, then it will not by default expire). https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/

Comment: how you solve your issue, i am just curious to know even with firewall block how you manage to connect graph.facebook.com to get authentication and values !!

Comment: See edit in original post.